# asp.net mvc 4 bootstrap jquery combobox autocomplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problems with the rendering of combobox in my project.

The autocomplete functionality works correctly. But you can not click to select the items in the combobox. Also the items are badly formed, and a descriptive label appears at the bottom.

Print:
http://tinypic.com/r/2jebtau/8

View:

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
   @Html.DropDownList("IdProcedimento", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PriorityID, new { @class = "form-control", id = "combobox" })
</div>
```

Script:

```
(function ($) {
            $.widget("custom.combobox", {
                _create: function () {
                    this.wrapper = $("<span>")
                  .addClass("custom-combobox")
                  .insertAfter(this.element);

                    this.element.hide();
                    this._createAutocomplete();
                    this._createShowAllButton();
                },

                _createAutocomplete: function () {
                    var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
                  value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

                    this.input = $("<input>")
                  .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                  .val(value)
                  .attr("title", "")
                  .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
                  .autocomplete({
                      delay: 0,
                      minLength: 0,
                      source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
                  })
                  .tooltip({
                      tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
                  });

                    this._on(this.input, {
                        autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            this._trigger("select", event, {
                                item: ui.item.option
                            });
                        },

                        autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
                    });
                },

                _createShowAllButton: function () {
                    var input = this.input,
                  wasOpen = false;

                    $("<a>")
                  .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                  .tooltip()

                  .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                  .button({
                      icons: {
                          primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                      },
                      text: false
                  })
                  .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                  .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
                  .mousedown(function () {
                      wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
                  })
                  .click(function () {
                      input.focus();

                      // Close if already visible
                      if (wasOpen) {
                          return;
                      }

                      // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                      input.autocomplete("search", "");
                  });
                },

                _source: function (request, response) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                    response(this.element.children("option").map(function () {
                        var text = $(this).text();
                        if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                            return {
                                label: text,
                                value: text,
                                option: this
                            };
                    }));
                },

                _removeIfInvalid: function (event, ui) {

                    // Selected an item, nothing to do
                    if (ui.item) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
                    var value = this.input.val(),
                  valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
                  valid = false;
                    this.element.children("option").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                            this.selected = valid = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    // Found a match, nothing to do
                    if (valid) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Remove invalid value
                    this.input
                  .val("")
                    this.element.val("");
                    this._delay(function () {
                        this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
                    }, 2500);
                    this.input.data("ui-autocomplete").term = "";
                },

                _destroy: function () {
                    this.wrapper.remove();
                    this.element.show();
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);

        $(function () {
            $("#combobox").combobox();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add these files:

```
jquery-ui.css  // this is for styling
jquery-1.10.2.js
jquery-ui.js"
```

And the following css classes are also required:

```
.custom-combobox {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}
.custom-combobox-toggle {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   margin-left: -1px;
   padding: 0;
   /* support: IE7 */
   *height: 1.7em;
   *top: 0.1em;
}
.custom-combobox-input {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0.3em;
}
```

And check if "form-control" class is having efects.

You have downloaded this from [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

Have you changed the paths of images(icons) which are being used by the plugins in CSS.

Comment: Thanks @AmanVirdi. The form-control was unnecessary. The combobox was malformed because of css: jquery-ui.theme.css. Using jquery-ui.css works. The icon still not show, but the path is correct. I solve the problem using glyphicon: .addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down")

Comment: That's great! @Cesar.